# How to format double value with zeros

Tags: c#, double, string-formatting, tostring

I would like to know is there is simple way to convert double value to a string as it is in C#? I used `.ToString("R")` and default `.ToString()` but it doesn't works.

Here is some test examples **0.00000000000000000000000001** gives me string **1.0E-26** and **29.999999999999999999994** converts to **30.0**. I don't want that. How such representation can be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

What representation do you want?

Check the MSDN for both [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) formatiing strings.

Comment: I want representation like 0.00000000000000000000000001 and 29.999999999999999999994 without rounding and scientific forms.

Comment: @PavelShchegolevatykh: So, `.ToString("f26")`, unless I miscounted your number of decimal places. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString).

Comment: Not works in my case because of rounding issue. It just rounds to 0 and 30.

Comment: @PavelShchegolevatykh: In the first case it works fine. In the second case you should read [the IEEE 754 standard](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/). The standard doesn't support that many significant figures, and I doubt that where ever you are getting these numbers from has that kind of precision anyway.

Comment: It was a requirement to show those numbers in such format. So I decide to rewrite code in Java. Thankfully it is pretty short. Java has built in feature for that: BigDecimal.valueOf(yourNumber).toPlainString()